# select values from specific column in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> Stored Procedure:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RT_SelectAll_BatchHistory_By_SchedulerTime]
@Skip INT,
@Take INT,
@ResultCode AS INT = 0 OUTPUT,
@ResultText AS VARCHAR(50)=NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY 
SELECT
       [SchedulerTime]
      ,[ExecutedOn]
      ,[FinishedOn]
FROM   [T_Scheduler] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [IsActive] = 1 
ORDER BY [SchedulerID]
OFFSET @Skip ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY
SET @ResultCode = 0
SET @ResultText='SUCCESS'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @ResultCode = -1
SET @ResultText='ERROR'
END CATCH
END
```

In this Stored procedure want to select All rows from SchedulerTime column and  Null values From executedOn and finishedOn.

how can achieve this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
       [SchedulerTime]
      ,[ExecutedOn]
      ,[FinishedOn]
FROM   [T_Scheduler] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [IsActive] = 1 AND [ExecutedOn] IS NULL AND [FinishedOn] IS NULL
```

This Worked Fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are aware of the dirty reads in your code, you can try something like this..

```
SELECT
       [SchedulerTime]
      ,[ExecutedOn] = NULL
      ,[FinishedOn] = NULL
FROM   [T_Scheduler] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [IsActive] = 1 
ORDER BY [SchedulerID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NULLIF in your SELECT Query

```
 SELECT
       [SchedulerTime]
      ,NULLIF([ExecutedOn],[ExecutedOn]) AS [ExecutedOn]
      ,NULLIF([FinishedOn],[FinishedOn]) AS [FinishedOn]
FROM   [T_Scheduler] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [IsActive] = 1 
ORDER BY [SchedulerID]
-----------------------------------------------    
SELECT
       [SchedulerTime]
      ,NULL AS [ExecutedOn]
      ,NULL AS [FinishedOn]
FROM   [T_Scheduler] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [IsActive] = 1 
ORDER BY [SchedulerID]
```